# jQuery smooth scroll link color change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed a smooth scroll using jQuery. One problem I'm facing is that when I click on the `navbar` links, there is a flickering.

Suppose if I click on the `Platform` link, there is a flickering on the `Why v9` link. Again when I click on the other links, there is flickering on the previous link. I'm not able to debug it.

Can someone please help me on this? It would be of great help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-item').click(function() {
    $(".nav-item").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).children().attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 800);
    return false;
  });

  //Active Link
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.nav-link').each(function() {
      var sectionOffset = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;

      if (sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```css
.navbar-nav {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
  color: #111;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #111;
}

/* navbar css code */

.navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item a:hover,
.navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item.active a {
  color: #89c353;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        Logo
      </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Why v9
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Platform</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Process</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section4">Benefits</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 feedback">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">LOREM IPSUM</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="section1" style="background:#d1d1d1; height:800px;"></div>
<div id="section2" style="background:#f0f0f0; height:800px;"></div>
<div id="section3" style="background:#d1d1d1; height:800px;"></div>
<div id="section4" style="background:#f0f0f0; height:800px;"></div>
```

Comment: @SajjadTabreez Well.. I try to reproduce your problem but I can't..
check this out
https://jsfiddle.net/JunsukPark/0z85417L/1/

Comment: @EhsanAli My codepen link  https://codepen.io/tabreez/pen/ejdbJw    You can check, if I click on the links there is a flickering on the previous link.

Comment: I think it is probably due to your scroll handler, that tries to highlight the menu item matching the currently visible section. While that might make sense while the user is slowly manually scrolling the page, I don’t think it does when automatic scroll happens due to navigation. (I already made my explicit choice which section I want to go to, so it isn’t even _helpful_ IMHO to highlight the ones in between “on the way”.) I’d use a flag to disable this effect during the automatic scrolling.

Comment: yes @JunsukPark you can check that one in your fiddle. when i click on the link i.e "platform" , there is a flikering on "why v9" link. similarly if i try clicking on other link, there is a slight flickering on the previous link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a global varriable to detact if the scrolling is by clicking or by scrolling:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var clickScroll = false; //ADDED

    $('.nav-item').click(function () {
    clickScroll = true; //ADDED
        $(".nav-item").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).children().attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 800, function(){
            clickScroll = false; //After the animation is finished set the varriable back to false
        });
        return false;
    });

    //Active Link

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
        //console.log(scrollbarLocation);
        $('.nav-link').each(function () {

            var sectionOffset = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;

            if (sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation && !clickScroll) { //ADDED
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
        })
    })

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this problem by writing one line.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // ADD
    if ($('html, body').is(':animated')) { return; }
```

If it's flag, you still have problem.
You click the nav menu, then you click the other nav menus until scroll is over.
I think it's good that to stop animation first.

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({~
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this in HTML

<script type="text/javascript">
// The function actually applying the offset
function offsetAnchor() {
  if (location.hash.length !== 0) {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 60);
  }
}

// Captures click events of all <a> elements with href starting with #
$(document).on('click', 'a.nav-link[href^="#"]', function(event) {
  // Click events are captured before hashchanges. Timeout
  // causes offsetAnchor to be called after the page jump.
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    offsetAnchor();
  }, 0);
});

// Set the offset when entering page with hash present in the url
window.setTimeout(offsetAnchor, 0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.nav-item').click(function () {
            $(this).prev().hide('fast').show('fast').hide('fast').show('fast').hide('fast').show('fast');
            $(".nav-item").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $($(this).children().attr('href')).offset().top
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });

        //Active Link

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
            $('.nav-link').each(function () {

                var sectionOffset = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;

                if (sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation) {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
                }
            })
        })

    });
```

```css
 .navbar-nav {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }


    .navbar-light .navbar-brand {
        color: #111;
    }


    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: #111;
    }




    /* navbar css code */

    .navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item a:hover,
    .navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item.active a {
        color: #89c353;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            Logo
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Why v9
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Platform</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Process</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section4">Benefits</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 feedback">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">LOREM IPSUM</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

 <div id="section1" style="background:#d1d1d1; height:800px;"></div>
 <div id="section2" style="background:#f0f0f0; height:800px;"></div>
 <div id="section3" style="background:#d1d1d1; height:800px;"></div>
 <div id="section4" style="background:#f0f0f0; height:800px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```